# Creating a handler by clicking on dynamic inline buttons

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I have dynamically created buttons in an array

```
keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
keyboard.row_width = 2
for i in range(0, len(adress)):
    keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(adress[i].text, callback_data="address_"))
bot.send_message(cid, 'Выберите адрес парковки', reply_markup=keyboard)
```

How do I track the click of one of the buttons and get the text from it? I set all the buttons the same callback_data. Perhaps you can do this `if call. data = = "address_":`, but how do I get the button text?

Comment: '*I set all the buttons the same callback_data*': don't ? The idea of `callback_data` is to know what button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

When a users clicks on an `InlineKeyboardButton` with `callback_data`, that results in an `CallbackQuery`. A [`CallbackQuery`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery) does not contain info about the text of the button that was clicked, but only about the `callback_data` the button had. So if you want to know the text associated with that button I recommend to make the `callback_data` unique per button. You could

- put that text directly into the `callback_data`
- make the `callback_data` some unique identifier and store a mapping identifier → text
- make the `callback_data` some unique identifier and extract the text by checking which of the buttons in `callback_query.message.reply_markup.keyboard` has that `callback_data`. Note that this doesn't work for callback queries from inline messages, is those don't bring along the `callback_query.message`

Personally I'd recommand the second solution.

Comment: How can this be done? I can make the `callback_data` unique, but then how do I create a handler and how do I get the message? `callback_data` will always be different because it is generated dynamically

Comment: > how do I create a handler
Can't answer that, as I'm not familiar with pyTelegramBotApi
> how do I get the message
if it's not an inline message, it will be contained in the update sent by Telegram