# Telegram Bot Use Button in Query

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am creating my first ever Telegram Bot on Python. For now, I managed to get an inline menu, but I cannot understand how to get the information from the last button (aka the text on the button that was pushed) to use it in the query for google doc. For example, if they check Button 3, I want to somehow access text 'Button 3' and use it in the query (data[data['type']=='Button 3']). Here is the code to help with understanding:

````
########################## Open connection with Google Sheets #############################

    client = gspread.authorize(creds)

    sheet = client.open('YodissiDay').sheet1

############################### Bot ############################################
    
    def start(bot, update):
      bot.message.reply_text(main_menu_message(), reply_markup=main_menu_keyboard())

    def main_menu(bot, update):
      bot.callback_query.message.edit_text(main_menu_message(), reply_markup=main_menu_keyboard())

    def first_menu(bot, update):
      bot.callback_query.message.edit_text(first_menu_message(),
                              reply_markup=first_menu_keyboard())
  
    def second_menu(bot, update):
      bot.callback_query.message.edit_text(second_menu_message(),
                              reply_markup=second_menu_keyboard())
    
    def third_menu(bot, update):
      bot.callback_query.message.edit_text(second_menu_message(),
                              reply_markup=second_menu_keyboard())

    def first_submenu(bot, update):
      bot.callback_query.message.edit_text(first_submenu_message(),
                              reply_markup=first_submenu_keyboard(bot, update))

   
    def second_submenu(bot, update):
      pass

    def error(update, context):
        print(f'Update {update} caused error {context.error}')

############################ Keyboards #########################################

     def main_menu_keyboard():
      keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton('First Choice', callback_data='m1')],
                  [InlineKeyboardButton('Second Choice', callback_data='m2')],
                  [InlineKeyboardButton('Third Choice', callback_data='m3')]]
      return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    def first_menu_keyboard():
      keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton('Beauty', callback_data='Beauty')],
                  [InlineKeyboardButton('One', callback_data='One')],
                  [InlineKeyboardButton('Two', callback_data='Two')],
                  [InlineKeyboardButton('Three', callback_data='Three')],
                  [InlineKeyboardButton('Main menu', callback_data='main')]]    
       return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    def second_menu_keyboard():
      pass

    def first_submenu_keyboard(bot, update):      
      data = gspread_dataframe.get_as_dataframe(sheet)
      data = data.astype({'Taken' : 'float64'})
      data = data[data['Taken']==0]
      gift_type = update.callback_query.data       
      gift_ideas = data[data['Type']==gift_type]    
      keyboard = []
      for row in range(0,gift_ideas.shape[0]):
          keyboard[row]=InlineKeyboardButton(text=gift_ideas['Name'][row],       url=gift_ideas['Link'][row])
      keyboard[gift_ideas.shape[0]+1]=InlineKeyboardButton('Main menu',    callback_data='main')
      return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)



############################# Messages #########################################
    
    def main_menu_message():
      return 'Hello 1:'

    def first_menu_message():
      return 'Hello 1_1:'

    def second_menu_message():
      return 'Hello 1_2:'

    def third_menu_message():
      return 'Hello 1_3:'

    def first_submenu_message():
      return 'Hello 1_1_1:'

############################# Handlers #########################################
# 
    Create bot object:
    bot = telegram.Bot(token=BOT_KEY)
    updater = Updater(BOT_KEY, use_context=True)
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(main_menu, pattern='main'))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(first_menu, pattern='m1'))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(second_menu, pattern='m2'))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(third_menu, pattern='m3'))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(first_submenu, pattern='Beauty'))
    updater.dispatcher.add_error_handler(error)    
 

    # Start polling:
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()```

All other recommendations/advices are also welcome! Keep in mind, that I try it step by step and for now I want to see how this 'Beauty' button would work! Other buttons lead to nowhere for now
````

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Creating a handler by clicking on dynamic inline buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67473044/creating-a-handler-by-clicking-on-dynamic-inline-buttons) about accessing the text of the clicked button.

Two additional remarks:

- You pass `use_context=True` to your `Updater`, but use old-style callback signatures (`def callback(bot, update):` instead of `def callback(update, context):`). Please see the [v12 transition guide for details](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-12.0).
- The names of four callbacks (`main_menu`, `first_menu`) imply that you are building some sort of interactive menu. If you add more functionality to your bot, this may become hard to maintain in this form. I suggest that you have a look at [ConversationHandler](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.conversationhandler.html) and the [`conversationbot2.py` example](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples#conversationbot2py) and see if that's helpful for your use case.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`